# Total time taken for Android AOSP build

Tags: android-source, android-build

I have recently build Android AOSP for emulator on a remote server. I wanted to know how much time it took for the complete build.
Is there any build log or build history which can inform me about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the log of your build then you can use the following command 'make' command to create a log file during build in place of simple 'make' command.

```
make -j<Number_of_cores_of_Processor>  2>&1 | tee build_log.txt
```

```
# Example : make -j6 2>&1 | tee build_log.txt
```

It will make a file of name 'build_log.txt' in your  directory.
In this file there will you can get all the build log and in the last line of  file you can see the time taken by your build.

You can use any name of build_log file on your each build.
To get each build log into different files.

Note : The above command is same make command which you use to build the project. There is just added only some command to save your build log in a file. So in place of only 'make' you can use that command to get the full log. If you run this command after running 'make' then you can not get full time taken by your build. Because it will not build the project from starting.
If you want to start your building from starting then you can clean your previous build after then you can run this make command and it will build your project from starting and take same time as your first build had taken.
Example :

```
make clean
make -j6 2>&1 | tee build_log.txt
```

In my cpu there are 8 core because of I have given 6 core to make.
You can check your cpu core by running 'nproc' and give accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

```
#### build completed successfully (19:29 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Comment: yes, i go the answer btw, by putting "time" infront of the command